# Char in currency format to number

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert a field that is in **varchar** but with a currency format into a number type.

The value comes in this format $999,999.99 but may also come as empty.

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
to_number(nvl(MYFIELD, '$0.00'),'FM$999,999,999,990.00')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
select TO_Number('$119,252.75','$999,999,999.99') from dual
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/109)**

Also your query is working fine for me

```
select to_number(nvl('$119,252.75', '$0.00'),'FM$999,999,999,990.00') from dual
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/113)**

Comment: It's working now... I'm not sure where that error was coming from but it's gone now.. thanks for the help anyway!